# Who is the destroyer in Isaiah 33:1?

Tags: isaiah

Isaiah 33:1

> Woe to **you**, destroyer, you who have not been destroyed! Woe to you, betrayer, you who have not been betrayed! When you stop destroying, you will be destroyed; when you stop betraying, you will be betrayed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is commonly held by scholars that Isa 1-39 were largely the work of Isaiah himself, who prophesied "in the days of Uzziah, Jotham, Ahaz, and Hezekiah" (Isa 1:1).  Therefore, Isa 1-39 was written in the late 8th century BC, covering the invasion, destruction, and exile of the northern kingdom of Israel by Assyria (722 BC).

Isa 33 is the 6th of the 6 laments in Isa 28-33, to appeal to God to be gracious to Israel (whose righteous people should have repented and accepted God's punishment) and defeat the destroyer Assyria, which came true in the well documented [Battle of Carchemish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_Carchemish) in 605 BC.

Therefore, **the destroyer referred to in Isa 33:1 is Assyria**.

> Do you think there could be another future fulfillment of this prophecy?

Personally, unlike the sign of Immanuel given to Ahaz [Isa 7:10-17](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Isaiah+7%3A10-17&version=ESV) which had a [dual fulfillment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_fulfillment) with the birth of Jesus, I haven't heard of a dual fulfillment of Isa 33, although of course some other chapters of Isaiah are yet to be fulfilled (such as [Isa 24](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Isaiah%2024&version=ESV)). I find the article [The Three Horizons of Old Testament Prophecy](https://www.christianitytoday.com/ct/2019/march-web-only/three-horizons-of-old-testament-prophecy-christopher-wright.html) very helpful for a general orientation on prophecy fulfillment.

Comment: Thanks for the scholarly answer. Do you think there could be another future fulfillment of this prophecy?

Comment: @TonyChan Personally, I haven't heard of a [dual fulfillment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_fulfillment) of Isa 33, although of course some other chapters of Isa are yet to be fulfilled.  I find the article [The Three Horizons of Old Testament Prophecy](https://www.christianitytoday.com/ct/2019/march-web-only/three-horizons-of-old-testament-prophecy-christopher-wright.html) very helpful.

Comment: Thanks as usual. In the future, if I forget to thank you, assume that I have done it in my heart :)

Comment: Excellent Answer!

Comment: @Tony Chan All prophecy is pattern, every time (that is, not looking to a one time fulfilment.)  and here is no exception. This prophecy was, is, and will be true for any invader of Israel. The same lament was issued over Babylon. That is, God allowed them to invade, but vowed to repay. (Which he did, via Medo-Persia). The same will be true for what is soon to happen